# Reading an Array File in python

Tags: python, arrays, file

I have this file which has an array of data written to it:

```
[[[ 32.  28.  28. ...  24.  24.  24.]
[ 30.  29.  29. ...  24.  24.  24.]
[ 29.  29.  28. ...  24.  24.  24.]
...
[137. 138. 129. ...  34.  34.  34.]
[140. 139. 128. ...  31.  34.  34.]
[136. 135. 122. ...  30.  30.  33.]]

[[ 40.  40.  40. ...  33.  33.  33.]
[ 38.  38.  37. ...  33.  33.  33.]
[ 37.  37.  37. ...  33.  33.  33.]
...
[140. 137. 132. ...  41.  43.  42.]
[139. 136. 129. ...  42.  43.  43.]
[140. 139. 133. ...  40.  42.  43.]]

[[ 10.   8.   7. ...   4.   4.   4.]
[  8.   7.   7. ...   4.   4.   4.]
[  7.   6.   6. ...   4.   4.   4.]
...
[101. 103.  94. ...  12.  13.  13.]
[105. 104.  92. ...  12.  13.  13.]
[ 99.  99.  99. ...   9.  10.  11.]]]
```

I do not know how to read from this file and use it within my code. Any help would be great! I have this within my code so far:

```
# Read and pre-process input images
n, c, h, w = net.inputs[input_blob].shape
images = np.ndarray(shape=(n, c, h, w))
for i in range(n):
    image = cv2.imread(args.input[i])
    if image.shape[:-1] != (h, w):
        log.warning("Image {} is resized from {} to {}".format(args.input[i], image.shape[:-1], (h, w)))
        image = cv2.resize(image, (w, h))
    # Swapping Red and Blue channels 
    #image[:, :, [0, 2]] = image[:, :, [2, 0]]
    # Change data layout from HWC to CHW
    image = image.transpose((2, 0, 1))  
    images[i] = image
    
    eoim = image
    eoim16 = eoim.astype(np.float16)
    
    val = []
    preprocessed_image_path = 'C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Ubotica/IOD/cloud_detect/'
    formated_image_file = "output_patch_fp"
    f = open(preprocessed_image_path + "/" + formated_image_file + ".txt", 'r')
    
    val = f
    print(f)
    print(val)
    # divide by 255 to get value in range 0->1 if necessary (depends on input pixel format)
    if(eoim16.max()>1.0):
        eoim16 = np.divide(eoim16,255)
        print(eoim16)


#f.close()

#print(val)
#val = np.reshape(val, (3,512,512))
eoim16 = np.ndarray(shape=(c, h, w))
#res = val

# calling the instance method using the object cloudDetector
res = cloudDetector.infer(eoim16)
res = res[out_blob]
```

But when I try to print out val and f (just to see if the data matches and is actually being read within my code nothing appears. Is there any way to solve this so that my array reads into val and I can use the data within my code? Much appreciated!

Comment: does your file have the `...` in it? If so how is the data even helpful?

Comment: @MZ The ... appears in the file itself. And this is because the data that gets loaded in is huge. I'm doing inference on satellite images and need to make sure the inferred results (from the file) match and are loaded within my file which is why I need to print and see if the data is exactly the same when it is being read into my file

Comment: when you are saving the data, use `np.save` and then load with `np.load`. This will save/load the array as is.

Comment: If you have to save it as a string, you could either set `numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)` then save it, or, convert your numpy array to a string, then compare that string to the string stored.

Comment: You won't be able to have any valuable equality checks when you're using truncated data.

Comment: ahh okay! I will try that now!

Answer (score -2):

Try using the eval function. It takes strings and interprets them as Python code.

```
a = eval(fileData)
print(a)
```

Comment: If I use eval I get a typeError saying this:                               
 val = eval(f)
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: you also have the issue where there are no commas lol, it's not a literal array

Comment: The file content shown is not valid Python code. ``eval`` cannot interpret it.

Comment: try doing ```eval('a = '+str(f.read()).replace('.', ','))```

Comment: @billschmidt626  I do this: eval('a = '+str(f.read()).replace('.', ','))
  File "<string>", line 1
    a = [[[ 32,  28,  28, ,,,  24,  24,  24,]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax, but get a syntax error?

Comment: add `.replace("...", "")`

Comment: your newlines need commas at the end of most of them as well

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming, I am in an internship working on this data set. I am still getting the syntax error 
   a = [[[ 32.  28.  28.   24.  24.  24.]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax . The carrot is pointing to the equal sign after a

Comment: and the ... just means there's massive amounts of data within this file, it's not showing every integer value

Comment: @Tristan Please can you answer the question in M Z's comment under the question itself. We will need to know whether the `...` appears in the file itself or whether that is something that you have added in the question.

Comment: My apologies. I just answered it underneath the question now!